# проверка множества условий

Tags: python

Есть код, в котором множество условий, потенциально каждое из которых может вызвать ошибку(выход за пределы массива). Как проверить все условия, если при возникновении ошибки(например на втором из них) проверка остальных прекращается?

```
def LoseCheck(x,y,_matrix,k): #проверка, является ли ход проигрышным
    try:  
        if (
            _matrix[x-2][y] == _matrix[x-1][y] == _matrix[x][y] == 1 
            or _matrix[x][y] == _matrix[x+1][y] == _matrix[x+2][y] == 1 
            or _matrix[x-1][y] == _matrix[x][y] == _matrix[x+1][y] == 1 
            or _matrix[x][y-2] == _matrix[x][y-1] == _matrix[x][y] == 1 
            or _matrix[x][y] == _matrix[x][y+1] == _matrix[x][y+2] == 1
            or _matrix[x][y-1] == _matrix[x][y] == _matrix[x][y+1] == 1 
            or _matrix[x-2][y+2] == _matrix[x-1][y+1] == _matrix[x][y] == 1 
            or _matrix[x][y] == _matrix[x+1][y-1] == _matrix[x+2][y-2] == 1 
            or _matrix[x-1][y+1] == _matrix[x][y] == _matrix[x+1][y-1] == 1 
            or _matrix[x-2][y-2] == _matrix[x-1][y-1] == _matrix[x][y] == 1 
            or _matrix[x][y] == _matrix[x+1][y+1] == _matrix[x+2][y+2] == 1 
            or _matrix[x-1][y-1] == _matrix[x][y] == _matrix[x+1][y+1] == 1
        ):
            if k%2 == 0:
                print("Второй игрок проиграл!")
                return 1
            else:
                print("Первый игрок проиграл!")
                return 1
        return 0  
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: предоставьте пример входных данных а то не особо понятно (как я понял это крестики нолики но могу ошибаться) и если это всë таки крестики нолики и они 3 на 3 то я думаю легче проверять все поле сразу а не по координатам

Comment: @FruitGames537 ну вообще это клондайк 10 на 10, поэтому проверять всё поле и сложно. https://www.iqfun.ru/printable-puzzles/klondike-igra.shtml

Comment: А за что отвечает переменная k? За игрока?

Comment: @FruitGames537 ага, типо нечетный это первый, четный второй. Но меня пока интересует как проверять эти условия

Comment: Вообще, первое что надо сделать, это при вызове функции вы не должны допускать выхода за пределы массива. Если такое есть, то это надо исправить. Если вы получите ошибку при проверке, то код останавливается и попадает в except. Можно проверять значения до обхода самого массива на предмет, будет ли выход за пределы или нет, но я бы правил в том месте, где вызывается функция.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Игровое поле как список списков

Прежде, чем решать эту задачу, нужно определить, что из себя представляет объект `_matrix`. Если это список списков, то кроме явной ошибки `IndexError: list index out of range` появится скрытая алгоритмическая ошибка при адресации ячеек отрицательными индексами. Для списка отрицательные индексы допустимы, а для задачи - нет.

В этом случае нам нужно переопределить класс `list` так, чтобы он корректно работал с недопустимыми индексами. Например:

```
from collections import UserList

class Line(UserList):
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        if isinstance(i, int) and (i < 0 or i >= len(self)):
            return Line()
        return super().__getitem__(i)
```

Чтобы иметь возможность работать со вложенными списками, здесь возвращается пустой список `Line()`. В итоге, при выходе любого индекса за пределы поля мы получим сравнение `Line() == 1`, которое отработает без ошибок и вернет ожидаемый `False`.

Игровое поле `_matrix` инициируем так:

```
n = 10                      # размер квадратного игрового поля
_matrix = Line()            # игровое поле

for _ in range(n):
    _matrix.append(Line([0]*n))   # заполняем поле нулями
```

Теперь функцию `LoseCheck` можем использовать как есть, хотя обрамление `try ... except` стоило бы убрать (оно лишено смысла).

### Игровое поле как словарь словарей

В качестве альтернативы мы могли бы использовать словари. Например:

```
from collections import defaultdict

default_value = 0       # содержимое ячейки игрового поля по умолчанию
_matrix = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: default_value))
```

В этом случае инициировать поле не нужно, оно заполняется по мере обращения к ячейкам. А при выходе индекса за пределы поля автоматически возвращается ноль. С этим объектом мы можем использовать функцию `LoseCheck` без иземений.

### Альтернатива LoseCheck

Чтобы не переопределять объект `_matrix`, мы можем переписать `LoseCheck`, ограничив запросы к полю допустимыми индексами:

```
def LoseCheck(x, y, _matrix, k):
    n = len(_matrix)     # размер игрового поля
    s = 3                # количество последовательных ячеек для проверки
    xx = range(x-s+1, x+s)
    yy = range(y-s+1, y+s)
    is_index = lambda x, y: 0<=x<n and 0<=y<n
    lines = [
        [(x, y) for x in xx if is_index(x, y)],                        # ячейки по оси x
        [(x, y) for y in yy if is_index(x, y)],                        # ячейки по оси y 
        [(x, y) for x, y in zip(xx, yy) if is_index(x, y)],            # ячейки по диагонали
        [(x, y) for x, y in zip(xx, reversed(yy)) if is_index(x, y)],  # ячейки по обратной диагонали
    ]
    # проверяем s последовательных ячеек вдоль каждой линии
    # пока все они не будут равны 1
    if any( 
        all(_matrix[i][j] == 1 for i, j in s_tuple)
        for line in lines
        for s_tuple in (line[i:i+s] for i in range(len(line)-s+1))
    ):
        if k%2 == 0:
            print("Второй игрок проиграл!")
            return 1
        else:
            print("Первый игрок проиграл!")
            return 1
    return 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Для того чтобы не было ошибок что индекс вышел за предел массива. Можно нормализовать значения и потом использовать то условие.

Вот пример:

```py
from math import ceil

def normalize(x, y):
  normalized_x = max(min((ceil((x + 1) / 3) * 3) - 1, 7), 2)
  normalized_y = max(min((ceil((y + 1) / 3) * 3) - 1, 7), 2)

  return normalized_x, normalized_y
```

Пример использования:

```py
def check_lose(x, y, matrix, k):
  x, y = normalize(x, y)
  # ваши поверки
```

Этот код работает без `try-except` (но если вы делаете `try-except` не оставляйте пустой блок `except`)

И таким образом числа находятся в диапазоне от `2` до `7`.
А эти числа не выходят за границы массива если прибавить/убавить `2`.

Ну а если не хочется загромаждать функцию то можно вынести условие в отдельную функцию.

Например так:

```py
def condition(x, y, matrix):
  if ...:
    return True
  elif ...:
    return True
  ...
  return False
```

И вот итоговая функция:

```py
def check_gameover(x, y, matrix, k):
  x, y = normalize(x, y)
  if condition(x, y, matrix):
    if k % 2 == 0:
      return True, 1
    else:
      return True, 2
  return False, None
```

Эта функция немного изменена и возращает кортеж со значениями `завершена ли игра`, и `игрока который победил` если завершена

Ну и вы можете доработать код условия например передавать еще и не нормализованные координаты и за счет них делать меньше проверок (ну это вы сами решайте как удобнее)

Comment: можете объяснить, что вы подразумеваете под "нормализовать значение?"

Comment: Ну типо если x = 14, y = -24 то для этого в любом случае не вызовется ошибок если нормализовать так как min(14, 7) == 7, а max(-24, 2) == 2 то есть если вы даже захотите выйти за предел массива у вас не получится и значения всегда будут в этом диопазоне от 2 до 7 а значит matrix[x + 2][y - 2] (matrix[7 + 2][2 - 2]) никогда не вызовет ошибку

Comment: И если ответ вам помог то поставьте зеленую галочку около ответа

Comment: я конечно понимаю, что это возможный вариант решения, но это не ответ на мой вопрос. Допустим есть 10 условий, из них любое может вызвать ошибку=>остановить код в данном сегменте, а мне точно нужно проверить каждое из десяти.

Comment: Ну по факту если значения будут нормализованы то ошибок не будет но если нужно как вы сказали то можно создать массив с условиями и в цикле вместе с try-except перебирать вот пример: list = [(lambda x, y, matrix: matrix[x][y] == 0), (lambda x, y, matrix: matrix[x-1][y+1] == 1), ...]\n for condition in list:\n try: if condition(x, y, matrix):\n return True\n except:\n continue

Comment: именно это мне и нужно было, большое спасибо. Напишите это отдельным ответом, чтобы я галочку поставил

Answer (score 1):

Вот еще одно возможное решение:

```py
def check(x, y, matrix):
  list = [
    lambda x, y, matrix: matrix[x] == y,
    lambda x, y, matrix: x < matrix[x][y],
    lambda x, y, matrix: matrix[x][y] > y,
    ...
  ]
  for condition in list:
    try:
      if condition(x, y, matrix):
        return True
    except:
      continue
  return False
```

Таким образом этот код будет выполнять условия и даже если произойдут ошибки код не завершится

Comment: по вашей просьбе я организовал это как ответ но я уверен что вам помог ответ который вы уже отметили галочкой но этот код конкретно отвечает на проблему и если кому-то понадобится такое реализовать то они смогут это сделать используя похожий код